# How to redirect to another page when i click on an item, in my navigation bar

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I use a navigation tool called [dock](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dock.jsf), from primefaces. I need to redirect to another page when i click on one of the items. 
The problem is that i need to find an alternative to the url attribute, this is because if i use it, the page gets redirected and the action attribute don't makes a call to the method is supposed to call.

This is how my nav bar looks like:

```
<h:form>
        <p:dock position="top">
            <!--Some other menu items ...-->
            <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="#{securityController.logOut}" rendered ="#{!securityController.checkLogged}"/>             
        </p:dock>   
</h:form>
```

This is the backing bean that is called to do the logout. It works good the only problem is that i don't get redirected.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

@EJB
private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;

public String logOut() {
        authentificationEJB.releaseUserState();
        return "main.xhtml";
    }
...
```

As you see i tried to return an String form the backing bean method, but doesn't work.

Could you help me find the way to redirect when i click on the p:menuItem?

Do you know maybe some javascript trick or something similar i can use to get redirected when i click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
return "main.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```